# require_once third party URL undefined variable issue

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to require_once a php file on a separate IP where there are variables within that file I need to access. Now I know its generally bad practice todo this however i'm limited in choices in terms of what I need to do.

I have another file on a different server needing to access the below extenerly hosted file. I need to access the `$db` object

```
<?php require('http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/dbtrans/db.php'); ?>
```

Currently this is throwing errors stating: Undefined variable: db

We are using MySQLi.

The code in db.php hosted externally is:

```
<?php

global $db = new mysqli('xxx', 'xxx','xxx', 'xxx');


if ($db->connect_error > 0){
        die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}
else{
        //echo ('it works!');
}


?>
```

Comment: You can not access $db object if the file is located like that in somewhere else. Why don't you have the db.php in the same machine? How are you limited?

Comment: You can't consume a PHP resource like this. You'll have to make the connection from your primary executing code, or start crafting webservices.

Comment: DB is hosted remotely and unable to grant access to outside access on mysql ports (it be great if we could)

Comment: Open the URL in your browser and look at the source code of the page (where you'd normally see the HTML). What you will see is the PHP code your script will get and execute. I doubt it has any PHP code inside. And if it has, the script will try to execute this, but on YOUR server - so if you don't have access to said database, it will not work. And if it works: Why include the file via network?